# Cannot connect to a hosted SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm getting an error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

This is my connection string :

```
<add name="Test_DatabaseEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/mymodel.csdl|res://*/mymodel.ssdl|res://*/mymodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Server=localhost;Database=decontac_test;Uid=decontac_decontac;Password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the email I got from the hosting company :

> For connection string use:
>   Server=localhost;Database=databaseName;Uid=userName;Password=password;

Please this is my first time hosting a site and this error is driving me crazy. when I use the credentials I am able to see the database in the SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Send your hosting company these two sentences: *Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.* and ask them to do the "look in the event log" for you (unless you can do it yourself). Something is quite wrong here.....

Comment: @marc_s so what my connections string right ?